# Странный отступ

Tags: css3, html5

Хочу сделать что-то вроде панели на которой располагается блок с цветным фоном. Но при приближении сайта(110%) появляется странный отступ, который портит внешний вид (светлая полоска).

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav#menu {
  height: 54px;
  border-top: 3px solid #142E4B;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #142E4B;
  position: relative;
}

nav#menu div.login {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 15vw;
  right: 6vh;
  background-color: #6181B4;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <div class="login">Войти</div>
</nav>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему появляется отступ сверху и как его можно убрать?

Comment: float для чего там ?

Comment: `display: block;`

Comment: Сверстать так, что бы при любых условиях все было хорошо - нереальная задача. Сценарии типа "если увеличить" - рассматривать стоит только если вы делаете целенаправленно сайт для слабо зрячих, и то, обычно это заложено в стандартном поведении.